# Recurrent Neural Network with multiple hidden layers

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I'm trying to implement a recurrent neural network which has N hidden layers in each subnetwork. Like from [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.07422):
[image]

Most of the guides I've read online have only one hidden layer for their RNN architecture. Is it possible to create multiple hidden layers per subnetwork in Tensorflow?

Comment: I belive you can use StackedRNNCells https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/StackedRNNCells

Comment: @AhmadAnis definitely not what he's looking for

Comment: U can implement it from scratch, which works pretty good in PyTorch, less with TF...